# Effective action as local functional?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

If we consider a canonical emsemble with matter fields $\psi$ coupled to electromagnetic field $A_\mu$. And we write system's partition function as the functional of electromagnetic field $A_\mu$, namely in path integral form, where we take $\hbar$ as unit:
$$Z[A_\mu]=\int D[\psi]e^{iS[\psi, A_{\mu}]}$$.

In this place, we do not know the microscopic form of interaction between matter and EM field. But we try to find some effective result of it.

Let $S_{eff}$ be defined by this way: $$Z[A_\mu]=e^{iS_{eff} [A_\mu]}$$.

If some "conditions"[**it is my question at**] are satisfied, we may write $S_{eff}$ as local functional as $A_\mu$, namely as $\int dx^3 ....$, if we focus on 2+1D space.

Then we can based on symmetry of system to expand $S_{eff}$ in lowest order of $A_\mu$ and their derivatives. With this approximating form of effective action, through $\delta(S_{eff})/\delta(A_{\mu})$, we can get current response of matter field to EM field.

**My question** is: what conditions should be satisfied so that we can write effective action as local functional of $A_\mu $?

It would be great if any example of conditions and some simple explanation for example can be given. Any recommended reference is also very good.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this taken from a reference?

Comment: It is from David Tong's note about Chern-Simons theory http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe/five.pdf.  It is near Eq(5.2). The note tells that if we consider the long range effect,  effective action can be written as a local functional. And discuss "long range" can be estimated from the energy gap. But I am confused about them.